# Is there any way to "star" or "favorite" a message in a thread in Google Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Like it says on the tin. I have a single message in the middle of a long conversation that I want to highlight and have easy to find, rather than having to remember that it's message number 35 out of 80 (or something like that) in the thread.

Is there any way to mark a single message as highlighted in Inbox?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I'm afraid there isn't. Your options for an individual message in a conversation are *Reply*, *Forward*, and *Print*.

Even if you "star" the message in Gmail, there's no indication of such in Inbox.

I think, at best, you can forward the message to yourself and then keep that pinned.

---

Do note that Inbox by Gmail is in wide preview, and they claim to be looking for your input. Use the "Feedback" tool to point out this lack.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Android app is exactly the same.

Answer (score -2):

At the far right side of the specified email there is a star that allows you to favorite it.

[image: Favorite a Gmail message]

If you use the search function in the header after that, and search for some of the words / a sentence in that message, it will pop up!

Comment: That's [Gmail](https://mail.google.com), not [Inbox](https://inbox.google.com). The question is about the latter. (See also: [Inbox by Gmail](https://www.google.com/inbox/).)